# Deleted /etc/mysql, What to do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

Here is the problem: I managed to delete /etc/mysql directory and I tried to recover my mistake but I made it worse.

When running "apt remove mysql-*" I get this:

> failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
> invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.

I tried various things like dpkg --configure, apt --reinstall and a lot of other things but nothing seems to work.

P.S. I made a copy of all databases and if a command delete everything it's not a problem at this point...

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Why not just reboot? Then starting the service will fail, so it is in a stopped (and failed) state

Comment: I already tried it but didn't work :(
When I run any "systemctl" command it says "mysql.service not found"